# Postgres similarity query score is pretty low for search text almost matching

Tags: postgresql

[image: postgress query result]

Query :

```
select similarity( 'GTudH','tud'), similarity ('GTudH', 'gtu'), similarity ('GTudH', 'gdh')
```

Above is the query result from Postgres, can someone explain why the 1st similarity score is only 0.1 but 3rd one is 0.25

Tested the same with Snowflake, which seems like alright.

[image: snowflake result set]

Comment: Don't post text as images.

Comment: Added the query in plain text format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges. The trigram similarity, as the [documentation states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), is measured by

> the number of trigrams they share.

You can easily see that, by that measure, the two strings in the first example have very little in common: they only share one trigram:

```
select show_trgm( 'GTudH'),show_trgm('tud')
```

| show_trgm | show_trgm |
| --- | --- |
| {" g"," gt","dh ",gtu,tud,udh} | {" t"," tu",tud,"ud "} |

Your Snowflake example, however, shows the [Jaro-Winkler similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance), which uses an entirely different algorithm, so it stands to reason that the result will also be quite different.